# React control rendering of the child components dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a parent React component and it has child components rendered within it.

```
<div id="parent">
    {<div style={{ visibility: isComp1 ? "visible" : "hidden" }}><MyComponent1 {...props}/></div>}
    {<div style={{ visibility: isComp2 ? "visible" : "hidden" }}><MyComponent2 {...props}/></div>}
    {<div style={{ visibility: isComp3 ? "visible" : "hidden" }}><MyComponent3 {...props}/></div>}
</div>
```

At a time, only one of the components would be rendered to the screen, depending on clicks to links on main parent page Link1/2/3. I control the visibility based on isComp1/2/3

Now within these child components, I have some API calls. I only want those API calls to be triggered when the respective links are clicked (i.e. Link1/2/3). However, I observe that despite setting the visibility to 'none' by default, all the 3 child components are rendered and all the child API calls are getting triggered.

Am I doing something wrong by using the visibility attribute ?

Answer (score 1):

The component is called and rendered, and the api calls are executed. The [`visibility` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) only effects the appearance of the DOM element on the page.

Use [conditional rendering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) instead:

```
<div id="parent">
  {isComp1 && <MyComponent1 {...props}/>}
  {isComp2 && <MyComponent2 {...props}/>}
  {isComp3 && <MyComponent3 {...props}/>}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional operators to hide/show the corresponding component:

```
<div id="parent">
    {isComp1 && <div><MyComponent1 {...props}/></div>}
    {isComp2 && <div><MyComponent2 {...props}/></div>}
    {isComp3 && <div><MyComponent3 {...props}/></div>}
</div>
```